# Giving an element from lower/upper triangular matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, linear-algebra, triangular

I have the upper triangular portion of a matrix, with the main diagonal stored as a linear array, how can the (i,j) indices of a matrix element be extracted from the linear index of the array?

For example the linear array :`[a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10]`is storage for the matrix

```
a0  a1  a2  a3
0   a4  a5  a6
0   0   a7  a8
0   0   0   a10
```

I've found solutions for this problem but without the main diagonal which is:

```
index = (n*(n-1)/2) - (n-i)*((n-i)-1)/2 + j - i - 1
```

And solution for the same problem but for a lower triangular matrix with the diagonal:

```
index = ((i + 1) * i / 2 + i).
```

Regards,

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. What have you tried? What results did it produce? Can you modify the one without the main diagonal to work with the main diagonal?

Comment: I've tried this for without the diagonal : k = (n*(n-1)/2) - (n-i)*((n-i)-1)/2 + j - i - 1
And this for the lower triangualar with the diagonal :((I + 1) * I / 2 + J).

Comment: @Bako can you include this in the question along with code you have used. What you have provided here is the logic and not everyone looks into the comments. So, please edit the question.

Comment: Do you have a mistake in “with the main diagonal stored as a linear array”? It appears that the linear *vector* stores the upper-triangular section, including the main diagonal?

Comment: @AhmedFasih No, I meant I store the upper triangular portion of a matrix including the main diagonal.

Comment: Got it! There’s a comma missing, but now I see 

Comment: I can’t imagine how someone might think this is a homework question… a professor would have to be truly satanic to stoop to this level of pointlessness. Everyone who works with sparse, banded, or triangular arrays has to figure out this kind of thing if their language/library doesn’t…

Comment: @AhmedFasih He is right, It is actually a homework from my OOP class. I just didn't how to define this method, but I figured out in the end :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution might be equivalent to [your’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39795684/500207), I haven’t checked:

```
index = N * i - ((i - 1) * i) / 2 + (j - i)
```

Here’s a complete Python test for it. I used Python because Numpy has [`triu_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html), which gives the upper-triangular indexes.

```py
import numpy as np

def mksquare(N):
    """Make a square N by N matrix containing 0 .. N*N-1"""
    return np.arange(N * N).reshape(N, N)

def mkinds(N):
    """Return all triu indexes for N by N matrix"""
    return [(i,j) for i in range(N) for j in range(N) if i <= j]

def ij2linear(i, j, N):
    """Convert (i,j) 2D index to linear triu index for N by N array"""
    return N * i - ((i - 1) * i) // 2 + (j - i)

def test(N):
    """Make sure my `mkinds` works for given N"""
    arr = mksquare(N)
    vec = arr[np.triu_indices(N)]

    inds = mkinds(N)
    expected = [arr[i, j] for (i, j) in inds]

    actual = [vec[ij2linear(i, j, N)] for (i, j) in inds]

    return np.all(np.equal(actual, expected))

"""Run `test` for a bunch of `N`s and make sure they're all right"""
print(all(map(test, range(2, 20))))
# prints True
```

Worth a blog post explaining how to arrive at this conclusion, but this’ll do for now .

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer! It is :

```
index = (n*(n+1)/2) - (n-i)*((n-i)+1)/2 + j - i
```

Answer (score 0):

Triangular matrices generalize to any dimension.  Suppose, for example, A[a,b,c,d,e] is non-zero only if 0<=a<=b<=c<=d<=e< N.  We can compress A to a linear array X where A[a,b,c,d,e] = X[a+B[b]+C[c]+D[d]+E[e]]

Where B[b] = {b+1 choose 2}, C[c] = {c+2 choose 3}, D[d] = {d+3 choose 4} and E[e] = {e+4 choose 5}.

These "offset" arrays can be computed without using multiplication or division as follows:

```
B[0] = C[0] = D[0] = E[0] = 0;

for(int t = 1; t < N; t++)
 {
  B[t] = B[t-1]+t;
  C[t] = C[t-1]+B[t];
  D[t] = D[t-1]+C[t];
  E[t] = E[t-1]+D[t];
 }
```